# How to save a numpy array to a webp file?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, rgb, webp

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

---

I have a numpy array `res`:

```
res = \
np.array([[[  1, 142,  68],
           [  1, 142,  74]],
   
          [[  1, 142,  70],
           [  1, 142,  77]],
   
          [[  1, 142,  72],
           [  1, 142,  79]],
   
          [[  1, 142,  75],
           [  1, 142,  82]]])
```

I would like to save it to a webp file and check if I can recover the result.

**Attempt I**

```
# save:
Image.fromarray(res.astype(np.uint8), mode='RGB').save("test.webp", "WEBP")
# check result:
np.array(Image.open("test.webp"))
```

This outputs:

```
array([[[  2, 143,  75],
        [  2, 143,  75]],

       [[  2, 143,  75],
        [  2, 143,  75]],

       [[  2, 143,  75],
        [  2, 143,  75]],

       [[  2, 143,  75],
        [  2, 143,  75]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Attempt failed, as these aren't the same numbers as I started with in `res`.

**Attempt II**

Now without `.astype(np.uint8)`:

```
# save:
Image.fromarray(res,mode='RGB').save("test.webp", "WEBP")
# check result:
np.array(Image.open("test.webp"))
```

This outputs:

```
array([[[ 2,  5, 31],
        [ 0,  0, 27]],

       [[17, 21, 40],
        [ 0,  0, 15]],

       [[ 0,  0,  3],
        [25, 32, 34]],

       [[ 0,  8,  1],
        [ 0,  7,  0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

This is even worse than Attempt I.

**How can I save a numpy array to a webp file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving your WEBP losslessly if you want the exact same values back, e.g. something like:

```
im.save('im.webp', lossless=True)
```

The specifics of what each file format can handle are documented [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp).